# how to change collapse inside collapse background color with different width inside. Accordion from bootstrap 4.5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
          <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria- 
expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            Collapsible Group Item #1
                        </button>
          </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show text-center" aria-labelledby="headingOne" 
 style="width:300px; background-color: yellow; margin:auto;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header text-center" id="headingTwo" >
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-link collapsed text-center" data- toggle="collapse" data- 
 target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" style="width:300px;">
                                        Collapsible Group Item #2
                                    </button>
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="card-body">
                  Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus wolf moon 
officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt 
aliqua put a bird on it assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                  craft beer sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings 
farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
 target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                            Collapsible Group Item #3
                        </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
          <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry wolf moon 
officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon 
tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single- assumenda shoreditch
            et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan 
excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you 
probably haven't heard of labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Hi so as you can see my collapse two is inside collapse one. And my collapse two width is a lot smaller than my collapse one width. The yellow background is currently only covering the width of collapse two when I open collapse one I want the yellow background to be the same width as collapse one. Thanks in advance. sorry I tried to run snippet but I'm not sure how to add the bootstrap links in snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria- 
expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Collapsible Group Item #1
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show text-center" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="background-color: yellow;">
          <div class="card-body mx-auto" style="width:300px; ">
            <div class="card ">
              <div class="card-header text-center" id="headingTwo" >
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-link collapsed text-center" data- toggle="collapse" data- 
 target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" style="width:300px;">
                      Collapsible Group Item #2
                  </button>
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="card-body">
                  Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus wolf moon 
officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt 
aliqua put a bird on it assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                  craft beer sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings 
farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
 target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                Collapsible Group Item #3
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
          <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry wolf moon 
officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon 
tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single- assumenda shoreditch
            et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan 
excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you 
probably haven't heard of labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/v0q3pxsh/